# How to migrate schema in Laravel without loss of existing data?

Tags: laravel-5

I have table named "user_table" has certain columns and table has filled with data. I want to add some more columns. So how can I migrate that new schema in Laravel without loss of existing data. Even I can not do rollback because when I will do then all stored data will be deleted. So, can somebody please help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new table columns in migrations without loss of data. If you alter a column or drop a column, then of course you will manipulate existing data. As long as you are only adding new columns, then you can run

```
php artisan make:migration alter_my_table_add_columns
```

and update your existing schema. Then you can safely run

```
php artisan migrate
```

In your new migration you would then add:

```
Schema::table('my_table', function ($table) {
    $table->string('my_new_column');
});
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-columns

Comment: Can you write the exact syntax if my table name is "user_table" and new column name is "rating".

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example for the migration,

Comment: Thanks man it works well ,but I have a question How to migrate database on server for making it live without loss of any data and also no need of modifying table ??